# Is there a way of removing rows from a HDF5 dataset?

Tags: python, dataset, hdf5, h5py

I have created a H5PY dataset, with around 2.1 million instances. The issue is I have filled all the rows apart from the last one. I want to remove the last row but unsure if it is feasible or safe to do.

This is a snippet of how the dataset is created:

```
shape = (dataset_length, args.batch_size, 2048, 1, 1)

with h5py.File(path, mode='a') as hdf5_file:
       array_40 = hdf5_file.create_dataset(
                  f'{phase}_40x_arrays',  shape, maxshape=(None, args.batch_size, 2048, 1, 1)


# either new or checkpointed file exists
# load file and create references to exisitng h5 datasets
with h5py.File(path, mode='r+') as hdf5_file:
      array_40 = hdf5_file[f'{phase}_40x_arrays']

     for i, (inputs40x, labels) in enumerate(dataloaders_dict):

          inputs40x = inputs40x.to(device)
          x40 = resnet(inputs40x)
          array_40[batch_idx, ...] = x40.cpu()

          hdf5_file.flush()
```

I'm not really sure if I need to copy all instances to a new dataset. I tried resizing, but that didn't work...

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, there is a dataset.resize() method. I have used before (to increase the size). By setting `maxshape=None` on axis 0, you have an unlimited # of rows when you resize. You should be able to do this: `array_40.resize(array_40.shape[0]-1, axis=0)` and get one less row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple example to demonstrate `dataset.resize()` for one dataset.

```
import numpy as np
import h5py

arr = np.random.rand(100).reshape(20,5)

with h5py.File('SO_61487687.h5', mode='a') as h5f:
     h5f.create_dataset('array1',  data=arr, maxshape=(None, 5) )

with h5py.File('SO_61487687.h5', mode='r+') as h5f:
     print ('Before:', h5f['array1'].shape)
     h5f['array1'].resize(10,axis=0)
     print ('After:', h5f['array1'].shape)
     h5f.flush()
```